# Customize Android Room Where Clause

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to filter a list of objects based on 2 spinner fields. The user can choose which fields they want to filter on and not all the fields must have a value (can be left blank). Instead of writing a ton of Queries in my Dao I would like to write one query.

My two fields are colour and category. If a specific colour is selected but no category is selected then I want my query to return all objects that have that colour, but if both colour and category are filled then I want my query to return those specific items and vice versa. In SQLite you can use this to return all objects that are black in the table regardless of category.

```
Select * from table where colour='black' and category = category
```

But when I send my variable to my query it buts the category into quotes so room is looking for the string "Category" instead of returning all categories. (Looks like this)

```
Select * from table where colour='black' and category = 'category'
```

Eventually I will need to add more fields which is why I do not want to write out Queries for each possibility.

I looked at using a RawQuery however my implementation didn't work. This was my interface inside my Dao

```
@interface RawDao
@RawQuery
List<Items> filterdItems(SupportSQLiteQuery query)
```

and inside my class

```
query = "Select * from table where colour='black' and category = category";
List<items> items = RawDao.filteredItems(query);
```

But I kept getting an error "Cannot reference non-static method from a static method..."

Is there a way to remove the quotes so I can return all the objects when nothing is selected in the spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following query will do what you want (at least in principle) :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE color = (CASE WHEN length(:color) THEN :color ELSE color END) AND category =  (CASE WHEN length(:category) THEN :category ELSE category END)")
    List<Items> filteredItems(String color, String category);
```

- this assumes passing an empty string if a field isn't selected.

The following is a working example based upon your code that demonstrates the above.

It assumes that color and category are Strings. If id's then the `CASE .... WHEN .... THEN .... END` would be a little different but the underlying principle would be the same. That is if a suitable value has been provided THEN the passed value is used ELSE the value of the column being processed is used.

- if color and category were id's (longs) then you could use

  - `@Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE color = (CASE WHEN :color > 0 THEN :color ELSE color END) AND category =  (CASE WHEN :category > 0 THEN :category ELSE category END)") List<Items> filteredItems(String color, String category);`
  - this assumes that id's are always greater than 0.
  - *this snippet hasn't been tested/run so may contain some errors.*

First the Entity **Table** :-

```
@Entity
class Table {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id = null;
    String color = null;
    String category = null;

    public Table(){}
    @Ignore
    public Table(String color, String category) {
        this.color = color;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

The **RawDao** interface :-

```
@Dao
interface RawDao {

    @Insert
    long insert(Table table);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE color = (CASE WHEN length(:color) THEN :color ELSE color END) AND category =  (CASE WHEN length(:category) THEN :category ELSE category END)")
    List<Table> filteredItems(String color, String category);
}
```

- Note for convenience/brevity List has been used (based upon your query querying a table called table, perhaps it should be item which would be better)

The @Database class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = {Table.class},version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract RawDao getDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;

    public static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"mydb")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Finally an activity that inserts some rows and then extracts data, writing it to the log, using the following permutations :-

1. neither color nor category (select all). i.e. empty strings passed.
2. only the color value passed
3. color and category values passed
4. only category value passed.

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    RawDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getDao();

        dao.insert(new Table("black","cat1"));
        dao.insert(new Table("green","cat1"));
        dao.insert(new Table("black","cat2"));
        dao.insert(new Table("green","cat2"));

        logTableInfo(dao.filteredItems("",""),"RUN1"); /* get everything as no values for either argument */
        logTableInfo(dao.filteredItems("black",""),"RUN2"); /*get color black irrespective of category */
        logTableInfo(dao.filteredItems("black","cat1"),"RUN3"); /* get color black in category cat1 */
        logTableInfo(dao.filteredItems("","cat1"),"RUN4"); /* get all that have cat1 as the category irresepctive of color */
    }

    private void logTableInfo(List<Table> items, String extra) {
        for(Table t: items) {
            Log.d("TABLEINFO" + extra,"Color is " + t.color + " Category is " + t.category + " ID is " + t.id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
2021-07-05 21:53:52.616 D/TABLEINFORUN1: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-05 21:53:52.617 D/TABLEINFORUN1: Color is green Category is cat1 ID is 2
2021-07-05 21:53:52.617 D/TABLEINFORUN1: Color is black Category is cat2 ID is 3
2021-07-05 21:53:52.617 D/TABLEINFORUN1: Color is green Category is cat2 ID is 4


2021-07-05 21:53:52.619 D/TABLEINFORUN2: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-05 21:53:52.619 D/TABLEINFORUN2: Color is black Category is cat2 ID is 3


2021-07-05 21:53:52.619 D/TABLEINFORUN3: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1


2021-07-05 21:53:52.620 D/TABLEINFORUN4: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-05 21:53:52.620 D/TABLEINFORUN4: Color is green Category is cat1 ID is 2
```

**Additional**

Here's an example of building a relatively flexible version where the SQL is built and as per the comment.

By flexible, it is not specific to a table/entity and it can cater for any number of column/value pairs (BUT only Strings values, BLOB (byte[]) would have to be converted). Utilising `ContentValues` could overcome the BLOB restriction). **However**, as with any use of @RawQuery you lose the compile time checking, so issues will result in runtime errors.

- Note this isn't fully comprehensive but rather an example that could cater for some situations:-

First the Dao :-

```
@RawQuery
List<Table> filteredItemsAlt(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

And then for convenience a method in the **Table** Entity :-

```
public static SimpleSQLiteQuery buildQuery(String fromClause, String[] whereColumns, String[] whereValues) {

    // Run query that returns nothing if columns and args (values) mismatch
    SimpleSQLiteQuery rv = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(fromClause + " WHERE 1 = 2", null);
    if (whereColumns.length != whereValues.length) return rv;
    // OK to go so prepare build variables
    ArrayList<String> bindArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder whereclause = new StringBuilder();
    
    // For each column and therefore arg/value
    for(int i=0; i < whereColumns.length; i++) {
        if (whereclause.length() > 1) whereclause.append(" AND "); // if where clause is not empty then add AND
        whereclause.append(whereColumns[i]).append(" = "); // column name = part
        // if value/arg is null or string is empty then affectively ignore (could alternatively ignore the AND and column = column)
        if (whereValues[i] == null || whereValues[i].length() < 1) whereclause.append(whereColumns[i]);
        // otherwise prepare to bind the value i.e ? in the SQL and value stored for bind
        else {
            whereclause.append(" ? ");
            bindArgs.add(whereValues[i]);
        }
    }
    Log.d("WHERE_CLAUSE","WHERE clause is " + whereclause.toString());
    // check to se if there is a where clause, if so build the full SQL
    if (whereclause.length() > 0 ) {
        rv = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(fromClause + " WHERE " + whereclause.toString(), bindArgs.toArray());
    } else {
        // otherwise build sql without WHERE clause
        rv = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(fromClause);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

- `fromClause` is the SELECT SQL including the fromClause
- `whereColumns` is the list of columns to be compared
- `whereValues` is the list of values (null or empty string to get all rows for the column)

In an activity (to replicate the first result) you could have :-

```
    logTableInfo(dao.filteredItemsAlt(Table.buildQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM `table`",
            new String[]{"color","category"},
            new String[]{null,null}
    )),"ARUN1");
    logTableInfo(dao.filteredItemsAlt(Table.buildQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM `table`",
            new String[]{"color","category"},
            new String[]{"black",null}
    )),"ARUN2");
    logTableInfo(dao.filteredItemsAlt(Table.buildQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM `table`",
            new String[]{"color","category"},
            new String[]{"black","cat1"}
    )),"ARUN3");
    logTableInfo(dao.filteredItemsAlt(Table.buildQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM `table`",
            new String[]{"color","category"},
            new String[]{null,"cat1"}
    )),"ARUN4");
```

and the result :-

```
2021-07-06 17:07:14.840 D/WHERE_CLAUSE: WHERE clause is color = color AND category = category
2021-07-06 17:07:14.841 D/TABLEINFOARUN1: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-06 17:07:14.841 D/TABLEINFOARUN1: Color is green Category is cat1 ID is 2
2021-07-06 17:07:14.841 D/TABLEINFOARUN1: Color is black Category is cat2 ID is 3
2021-07-06 17:07:14.841 D/TABLEINFOARUN1: Color is green Category is cat2 ID is 4
2021-07-06 17:07:14.841 D/WHERE_CLAUSE: WHERE clause is color =  ?  AND category = category
2021-07-06 17:07:14.843 D/TABLEINFOARUN2: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-06 17:07:14.843 D/TABLEINFOARUN2: Color is black Category is cat2 ID is 3
2021-07-06 17:07:14.843 D/WHERE_CLAUSE: WHERE clause is color =  ?  AND category =  ? 
2021-07-06 17:07:14.846 D/TABLEINFOARUN3: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-06 17:07:14.847 D/WHERE_CLAUSE: WHERE clause is color = color AND category =  ? 
2021-07-06 17:07:14.849 D/TABLEINFOARUN4: Color is black Category is cat1 ID is 1
2021-07-06 17:07:14.849 D/TABLEINFOARUN4: Color is green Category is cat1 ID is 2
```

- Note that the above has been put together relatively hastily, so could probably do with some tweaks, so again more of an in-principle example. *e.g. what if you wanted it ordered? (rhetorical)*

Comment: Thanks Mike! Worked like a charm. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @olivia.dayaram the alternative would be to build an @RawQuery, as opposed to an @Query,  So you would build either `SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = ? AND color = ?` (the value) or (where category hasn't been provided as one of the permutations) `SELECT * FROM table WHERE category = category AND color = ?` i.e. no value then hard coded column name rather than ?. For numerous columns the SQL could be built by a suitable method and could therefore be simpler.

Comment: I built the RawQuery 
`RawQuery
    List<Item> getItems(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
`
and this is my code for the query
`SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("Select * from table where category = category")
List<item> itemList = RawDao.getItems(query);
`
But it keeps returning null. If I run the same query on my table I get results. In the documentation I see 
`
"SELECT * FROM Song WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1",
     new Object[]{ songId});
` 
Do I need to use the "new Object.." in my code?

Comment: @olivia.dayaram if you have any values to be bound (i.e. **`?`**'s) then you need to pass Object[]. In the example as per the **Additional** section, you will see that the Object[] is passed if the WHERE clause is not empty even though the Object[] may be empty (as in the case when neither category nor color is provided, the **A1RUN** ).  I should have sent a comment saying to refer to the **Additional** section as it shows you a working example.

Answer (score 0):

`RawDao` is an interface and We cannot directly call method on interface, Please check this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-call-an-interface-method-in-java) for more info `How to call an interface method`

You need to create the abstract instance of `RawDao` in `Database` class and need to get instance of `Database` class

For example:

```
@Database(entities = {DataClass.class}, version = dbversion in int, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppRoomDb extends RoomDatabase {
    private static String TAG = AppRoomDb.class.getSimpleName();
    private static volatile AppRoomDb INSTANCE;
    public abstract RawDao rawDao();

    public static AppRoomDb getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (AppRoomDb.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AppRoomDb.class, ROOM_DB_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now you can get the method of `RawDao` interface using:

```
query = "Select * from table where colour='black' and category = category";
List<items> items = AppRoomDb.getInstance(context).rawDao().filteredItems(query);
```

For more info regarding RoomDb, You can check this  [link](https://medium.com/android-news/pre-populate-room-database-6920f9acc870).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `filteredItems` via interface name `RawDao`. Instead, you should call it via database instance. Use Database instance to get the `DAO` and then call `filteredItems` methods with the desired query:

```
query1 = "Select * from table where colour='black'";
query2 = "Select * from table where category = 'your_category'";
query3 = "Select * from table where colour='black' and category = 'your_category'";
SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(query1) //Use query1 or query2, query3 
List<items> items = rawDao.filteredItems(query);
```